# How to trigger the click event of a JQuery tab element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with triggering the click event of one of the elements, i added to my Jquery tab. As you know, when one of the links in a Jquery tab is clicked, it changes the content of a specified div to the contents of the div with an id specified in the `'<a> </a>'` of one of the Jquery tab elements (in this case the one that has just been clicked)..

What I want to do is trigger the click event on this element (i.e the Jquery tab group element that has just been clicked) when i click another element in my document (i.e the element with the id `#viewClassesNavBtn`).

-------This the call back function code snippet ------

```
$(document).ready(function(){

          $("#viewClassesNavBtn").click(function(){
            <!--  $("#dasCBtn").click();-->

            document.getElementById('dasCBtn').click();
              });
});
```

------This is the jquery tab ui section------

```
<ul id="tabs_ul" style="background-color:transparent; border:none;">
<li class="dashBBtn" id="dasBtn"><a href="#borderArmourSummary">Dash   Board</a></li>
<span class="divider">|</span>
<li class="dashBBtn" id="dasCBtn"><a href="#divClasses">Classes</a></li>
<span class="divider">|</span>
<li class="dashBBtn" id="dasPBtn"><a href="#divProfiles">Profile</a></li>
<span class="divider">|</span>
<li class="dashBBtn" id="dasBStn"><a href="#divSettings"> Settings</a></li> 
                </ul>
```

When I click the element with id `#viewClassNavBtn`, I expect it to simulate the tab switching event of the JQuery UI but it doesn't. I get the feeling it is not possible, but I am inexperienced with JQuery UI tabs and stuff, so if it is possible, please help.

Comment: There is no element with id `viewClassNavBtn` or even `viewClassesNavBtn`

Comment: <li class="btnHv animate" id="viewClassesNavBtn">View Classes </li>

Comment: It in another div that inside the jquery tab_ui container

Comment: What happens when you use the jQuery `.click()` method instead of the DOM `.click()` (which is obsolete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI is not attaching the click event to the `li` items, it's attaching it to the link.  Simply move the `id` tags onto the link and problem solved.  Included a function to simulate a mouse click instead of relying on the technically obsolete `.click()` method (which doesn't seem to show any signs of going away)

```js
function clickTab(tab) {
    let click = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        synthetic: true,
        view: window
    });
    tab.dispatchEvent(click);
}

$( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    $(".navBtn").click(function() {
        let tab = document.getElementById(this.dataset.for); 
        if (document.getElementById("simulate").checked) {
            clickTab(tab);
        } else {
            tab.click();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="dashBBtn"><a id="dasCBtn" href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li class="dashBBtn"><a id="dasPBtn" href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li class="dashBBtn"><a id="dasBStn" href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Stuff in the C tab</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Stuff in the P tab</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Stuff in the S tab</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
<button class="navBtn" type="button" data-for="dasCBtn">C</button>
<button class="navBtn" type="button" data-for="dasPBtn">P</button>
<button class="navBtn" type="button" data-for="dasBStn">S</button>
<input id="simulate" type="checkbox" checked>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: No worries.  I think one reason someone might prefer the `clickTab` method is because it explicitly sets the `synthetic` property of the `MouseEvent`.  If you would mark this answer as "accepted", that would be cool - it's the check check box under the vote.

Comment: Just to be clear, the DOM `.click()` method isn't itself obsolete, the DOM standard it's defined (L2) in was obsoleted by L3 and L4.  But since they have not deprecated it, it should be fine.  However, L4 did make a lot of changes to Events